# Thread doesn't join with the main thread

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I'm having a problem with my logger class.
Here's the code:

```
#include "Logger.h"

Logger::Logger()
{
    fileName = new string("log.txt");
    out = new ofstream(*fileName, ofstream::out);
    stream = new vector<string>;
    changed = new bool;
    condition = new condition_variable;
    myMutex = new mutex;
    running = new bool;

    if (running)
    {
        PostQuitMessage(500);
    }

    if (!out->is_open())
    {
        exit(3);
    }
    *running = false;

    T = new thread(&Logger::myrun, this);
}

Logger::~Logger()
{
    delete fileName;
delete out;
delete stream;
delete changed;
delete condition;
delete myMutex;
delete running;
delete T;
}

void Logger::myrun()
{
    *running = true;

    while (*running)
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(*myMutex);
        condition->wait(lock, [this] { return *changed; });

        for (int c = 0; c < stream->size(); c++)
        {
            *out << stream->at(c) << endl;
        }

        stream->clear();

        *changed = false;
    }
    Sleep(100);
}

void Logger::log(string msg)
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(*myMutex);

    stream->push_back(msg);

    *changed = true;
    condition->notify_one();
}

void Logger::stop()
{
    *running = false;
    *changed = true;
    condition->notify_one();
    T->join();
    out->close();
}
```

The thread hangs after the line T->join();

My question is - why does it hang? And how should I resolve it? Please show me in code :)

Thanks in advance!

P.S. All variables are pointers because I use this code is in a dllexport, VS gives me a lot of warnings that it "needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Logger'". If anyone has some tips on this one - You are welcome to post :D

Comment: Which T->join() ? The one in your stop() method or the destructor?  Might be a good idea to put out->close() after T->join().

Comment: Stopping a thread in a dtor is generally not a good idea, as the lifetime of the object ends when the dtor call starts.

Comment: Uhm... well this is awkward. Changed something (don't remember what), went to the little boys room, came back, tried to run it and it worked... Not sure why.

Comment: Do you call `Logger::stop`? If so you call `join` twice. I is UB. You also have awful lot of race conditions there. All accesses to your variables should be protected by mutex after creation of the thread.

Comment: Thank You all, I fixed the issue, if someone would post the answer, I'd select it. Also, @zch: I'm fairly new to multithreading, have tried before to protect the variables only with mutex, but I failed. Could You post the code as to how I should do it?

Comment: I reverted your edit, because adding [FIXED] to the title and explaining it in the text isn't how StackOverflow works. If you want to answer your own question to explain the solution you found, you can do so by [answering your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). You can even accept that answer as correct (although you won't gain any rep by doing so). Thanks. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite Thank You very much, sorry for not following the rules :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by puttin the destructor code into the method stop and closing the file after joining the thread. I think